# Search became slower after adding index

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, indexing

The mongodb collection stores documents of the form:

```
{url: "/url", ip: "0.0.0.0", ua:"useragent", time: 51}
```

I make a selection with the following code

```
collection.aggregate([
{ $group: { _id: "$url", count: { $sum: 1}, time: { $sum: "$time"} }},
{ $project: { _id: 1, count:1, time: { $round : [{$divide: ["$time", "$count"]}, 0] } } },
{ $sort: { count : -1 } },
{ $limit: 100}
]).toArray(callback);
```

With `700,000` documents, the request takes 3 seconds, which is somehow very long, added an index to the `url` field

```
collection.createIndex({ url: 1})
```

After that, requests began to be processed 2 times longer, after deleting the index, the execution time returned to 3 seconds.

1. How to speed up query execution?
2. Why did adding an index result in poor results?

Comment: You can try playing around with `explain` in your aggregate. My guess is it is using index-based searching, but still needs to look up every element to get the `time` attribute. You can can try adding a combined index with both `url` and `time`: `collection.createIndex({ url: 1, time: 1})`.